# Loading services methods before and after broker has started

Tags: moleculer

Please, clarify the methods that can be used for loading services **before** and **after** broker has started.

Tia

Comment: @Icebob replied at GitHub: Call the broker.loadService() before or after broker start.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). However, be sure your question contains enough information so that it's possible for anyone to be able to determine your answer actually is the solution (i.e. not just because you say it is).

Answer (score 0):

You can load services whenever with `broker.loadService()` method.